# Points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are coplanar and Determining Area of Triangle in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across this question in my textbook while working on some problems:

> Find the criterion for four points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to be coplanar; then find the formula involving the cross product for the area of a triangle with vertices given at three given points.

My work/ thoughts:

I'm not sure about the first part of the question, but I know for the second part of the question that the formula they're probably talking about is that $\frac{1}{2}(\vec{a} \times \vec{b})$. I know that formula would give me half of the area of a parallelogram in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but this question asks for the vertices at $\mathbb{R}^3$, so I don't know if that formula still applies or not. Also to get the three edges of the triangle, I'd just use the distance formula to determine their lengths (if need be). I'm not sure what to do,as typically when there are three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, I usually take the triple scalar product, but that would give me the volume, not the area. So any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Edit: Just realized that the formula I talked about would work if I figured out if the three vectors were coplanar. (Right?) I can use the triple scalar product and if it equals 0, then it is indeed coplanar.

Comment: There is no single criterion for four points to be coplanar. That any three of the points determine the same plane is a good one, and maybe the one that your book intends.

Comment: @EricTressler: Sure there is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1,...,x_4$ be the four points. Compute $\alpha = \det \begin{bmatrix} x_1-x_4 & x_2-x_4 & x_3-x_4 \end{bmatrix}$. If $\alpha = 0$ they are coplanar.

There is nothing special about $x_4$, any other 'origin' point would suffice (from a theoretical perspective).

This is not a numerically stable way, but is fine theoretically.

**Note**: Since $\langle a, b \times c \rangle = \det \begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \end{bmatrix}$, it should be clear that $\alpha = \langle x_1-x_4, (x_2-x_4) \times (x_3-x_4) \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the four points be $x,y,z,w$. Let $a=x-w,\ b=y-w$ and $c=z-w$. Then the four points are coplanar if and only if $(a\times b)\cdot c=0$. Do you know why?

Comment: I think so. If $(\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) \cdot c=0$, then $\vec{a} \times \vec{b}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{c}$.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan Yes, but there is another possibility: $a\times b=0$. Anyway, as the scalar triple product is zero, the vectors $a,b,c$ form a parallelepiped of zero volume. Hence they must collapse onto a plane.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would it matter which points I subtracted? (For example if I replace $b= y-w$ with $b=w-y$) ?

Comment: @SujaanKunalan: See my comment above... The answer follows from properties of the determinant.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan No, it wouldn't matter. As copper.hat says, this follows from the properties of determinants.